# Flutter: Cards UI/UX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to recreate the following layout in order to improve my skills, but I'm not sure how to do that, and I would appreciate it if any of you could help me with this problem.

[image]

I have a page that is going to display a list of card widgets with some widgets inside them.
The cards have been been the ORANGE and DARK_RED rectangles.

**THE PROBLEM**

How can I make that at the moment when the user will press the ADD button to add another card on the top of the old one? At the same time, I want that the card below to be a bit bigger in order to make the distinction between them.

Is there anyone how knows how can I achived this? Or is there any package that can help me a widget at list somewhat similar with what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack to create two containers on top of each other. Or you can also use cards inside stack widget to achieve this. Just create a function and make sure your 2nd dark red container or card widget is in there, then in add button's on press use setstate to call that function.

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question properly, but... I cant user a stack because I don't have 2 containers, I have N containers. The idea has been if the user will click ADD and is going add another card on top of that.